# Why MACUSA and not MCUSA (Magical Congress of the United States of America)?

Tags: fantastic-beasts

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find them*, we learn about **the Magical Congress of the United States of America** (shortened **MACUSA**).

[image]

Indeed they abbreviate it to this acronym in common speech (pronounced "Ma-koo-za"), but is heavily implied to be an official abbreviation, much like SWAT (Special Weapons and Tactics) and Navy SEALs (Sea Air Land), both in and out of universe.

[image]

Where is the first ***A*** in **MACUSA** coming from (i.e. obviously from **Ma**gical, but how come it gets away with using the letter **A** when it isn't an initial for one of the words that it's abbreviating)? Is there an official reason or out-of-universe explanation?

Comment: Um, **MA**gical by any chance?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson My question is why MACUSA and not MCUSA, it seems odd for an acronym to randomly add a letter that isn't an initial, but I explained in my own answer (thanks to some deeper reading into *acronyms*) that there isn't a standardized ruleset for making acronyms.

Comment: Because it speaks much better as a word, as you realized, too?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Again, I realize that it's an acronym, and that acronyms, especially when longer than 3 characters, are more easily spoken than initialisms. It is entirely obvious that **MA** comes from **Ma**gical, and that MACUSA is easier to pronounce as an acronym than MCUSA, though my question was more precisely "Why MACUSA and not MCUSA" in the sense that "How come it gets away with using a letter in its acronym that isn't the initial for one of the words it's abbreviating?". I will take the blame for the miscommunication, should word it more precisely.

Comment: That's why I was commenting, not answering, but thinking back on your question, it's not even relevant to movies and TV, but to linguistics in general. It could as easily be applied to SEAL or Gestapo. Going back to topic, I have no sources, it just sounds plausible. Someone picks the name. Maybe a committee. There are a few rules for picking the name, there might be a vote. It changes depending if it's a private company, or a state service as well. In the end, it's called whatever people in power wanted to call it. (I doubt the author wrote the lore for the naming of the MACUSA congress.)

Comment: It's actually pronounceable as a word either way - no-one would ever fumble with how to pronounce McDonald's, would they? ...but that in itself might be **why** the added A, so no-one [even the most gullible] would think it was a new burger product, McUSA ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin *"It's actually pronounceable as a word either way*" I agree. I find the implied unofficial trademarking (by this I mean cause of product confusion) of the *Mc* prefix by McDonald's quite tragic, seeing as the *Mc* (meaning *son of*) is almost ubiquitous in Irish, or of Irish ancestry, surnames. Indeed, that is how McDonald's got *its* name in the first place xD.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - absolutely. Being of Scottish extraction [though by a circuitous route] myself - I picked McDonald's as just being probably the most well-known example of that pronunciation, and actually the McUSA was a late thought, as I was typing ;)

Comment: I understand saying phonetically, "MACUSA" (even if at first I found myself wondering what the Yakuza had to do with the plot) because that's what we do with most pairs of consonants going one after the other, we add an invisible vowel when we speak it. What bothers me is seeing it in text. You can look at 'MCUSA' and think and say "MACUSA" as if the 'ma' is like the m in phrases like m'darling, or m'dear. That invisible vowel should stay invisible, though, in my opinion.

Comment: It's supposed to be M(a)COTUS like POTUS or SCOTUS...

Comment: Maybe it would be too much like branding as in MC USA McDonald's might not like it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**MA**gical **C**ongress of the **U**nited **S**tates of **A**merica (**MACUSA**), is an acronym.

According to the Wikipedia article on *[Acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym)*

> There is no universal standardization of the various names for such abbreviations and of their orthographic styling.

In other words, an acronym needn't follow any universal rules for abbreviating, such as *only* using the **initials**, because there is no standard way of forming acronyms.

From the wiki's list of different example types:

> - Pronounced as a word, containing non-initial letters
>
>   - Amphetamine: **a**lpha-**m**ethyl**ph**en**et**hyl**amine**
>   - Gestapo: **Ge**heime **Sta**ats**po**lizei ('secret state police')
>   - Interpol: **Inter**national Criminal **Pol**ice Organization
>   - Nabisco: **Na**tional **Bis**cuit **Co**

If we look at **Gestapo** or **Interpol**, both of which are comparable to **MACUSA**, we can see that J.K Rowling's decision for this acronym is certainly justifiable when looking at real-life, out-of-universe examples.

Answer (score 9):

Like Napoleon said, the acronym comes from **MA**gical **C**ongress of the **U**nited **S**tates of **A**merica.  Much like the "E" in NAVY SEALs, which you yourself brought up.  (**SE**a **A**ir **L**and)

Sometimes people get creative with the rules for building an acronym, in order to turn it into a pronouncable "word."  This is especially true in fictional stories where the author can control what an agency's initials are, and doubly so in anything involving spies or secret agencies.  (Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., anyone?)

> **Hill:** What does S.H.I.E.L.D. stand for Agent Ward?
>
> **Ward:** Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement and Logistics Division.
>
> **Hill:** And what does that mean to you?
>
> **Ward:** That someone really wanted our initials to spell "SHIELD."

Comment: In contrast with SHIELD, MACUSA is not a word (though it is pronounced as one, making it an acronym, just like SHIELD), so I don't think J.K Rowling (out-of-universe) or the American founders of MACUSA (in-universe) "really wanted" their initials to spell MACUSA, the same way Ward thinks of SHIELD.

Comment: Cheers for pointing out that SEAL (in my own question) follows the same structure, didn't even notice that xD, and I use this acronym a lot.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I agree, which is why I put the word "word" in quotes.  In the case of MACUSA, I think it's safe to say they added the "A" just to make it pronounceable.  SHIELD was just an easy, and extreme, example of people forcing words into an acronym :)