# What's the common thread between Fargo and Shut Eye?

Tags: production, fargo-tv, shut-eye

I started watching Shut Eye on hulu and I realized some actors from the Fargo series on FX are in it, [Jeffrey Donovan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0232998/) and [Angus Sampson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0760151/).  I don't believe in coincidences but I can't find a producer or exec that's involved with both shows.

Answer (score 2):

If you lost your job one day, would it be a coincidence that you started looking for another job the next day?  Would it be a coincidence that your friend whom you've worked with in the past helped you find a new job?

I haven't been watching *Fargo* or *Shut Eye,* so I don't know the particulars of these two actors' situations in either show.  The "losing your job" analogy may not be entirely accurate, but I think it makes the point - *it's not a coincidence that actors go from one show to another, sometimes in groups.*  They can network with other actors or crewmen to find new gigs.  There doesn't need to be an exec in common between two shows for multiple actors who know each other to turn up in multiple shows together.

I've noticed similar goings on with the main cast from *Buffy the Vampire Slayer,* for example.  Alyson Hannigan (Willow) eventually landed a new role on *How I Met Your Mother,* and then her former *Buffy* co-star ([and RL husband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alyson_Hannigan#Personal_life)) Alexis Denisof showed up in a recurring role on *HIMOM* * as well.  I'm not aware of any major execs in common between the two shows, but they obviously networked among themselves, what with being married and all.

In particular, with the recent trend towards shorter TV seasons (10-ish episodes instead of 22-ish) I've noticed that some actors are taking on larger roles in two or three shows at a time, presumably because the smaller number of episodes means less filming time per season, and therefore more free time to pursue side projects.  So, the fact that Mr Donovan helped Mr Sampson (or vice versa) land a new role may not be indicative of either actor leaving the former show.

* **H**ow **I** **M**et y**O**ur **M**other.  I know it's not the traditional way to make an acronym, but I like this one better than HIMYM.  [Related](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63638/why-macusa-and-not-mcusa-magical-congress-of-the-united-states-of-america/63639#63639)

Comment: snarky but fair

Comment: It was meant to be cheeky, but not offensive.  Hopefully no offense was taken ;)

Comment: no more than the downvotes ;)